# printf(), fprintf(), wprintf() and NSlog() won't print on XCode

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, xcode4.2, wchar-t

I'm doing a small app for evaluating and analyzing transfer functions. As boring as the subject might seem to some, I want it to at least look extra cool and pro and awesome etc... So:

- Step 1: Gimme teh coefficients! [A bunch of numbers]
- Step 2: I'll write the polynomial with its superscripts. [The bunch of numbers in a string]

So, I write a little C parser to just print the polynomial with a decent format, for that I require a `wchar_t` string that I concatenate on the fly. After the string is complete I quickly try printing it on the console to check everything is ok and keep going. Easy right? Welp, I ain't that lucky...

```
wchar_t *polynomial_description( double *polyArray, char size, char var ){

    wchar_t *descriptionString, temp[100];
    int len, counter = 0;
    SUPERSCRIPT superscript;

    descriptionString = (wchar_t *) malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 2);
    descriptionString[0] = '\0';

    while( counter < size ){

        superscript = polynomial_utilities_superscript( size - counter );
        len = swprintf(temp, 100, L"%2.2f%c%c +", polyArray[counter], var, superscript);
        printf("temp size: %d\n", len);

        descriptionString = (wchar_t *) realloc(descriptionString, sizeof(wchar_t) * (wcslen(descriptionString) + len + 1) );
        wcscat(descriptionString, temp);

        counter++;

    }

    //fflush(stdout); //Already tried this
    len = wprintf(L"%ls\n", descriptionString);
    len = printf("%ls**\n", descriptionString);
    len = fprintf(stdout, "%ls*\n", descriptionString);
    len = printf("FFS!! Print something!");

    return descriptionString;

}
```

During the run we can see `temp size: 8` printed the expected number of times ONLY WHILE DEBUGGING, if I run the program I get an arbitrary number of prints each run. But after that, as the title states, wprintf, printf and fprintf don't print anything, yet `len` does change its size after each call.

In the caller function, (`application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, while testing) I put an NSLog to print the return string, and I dont get ANYTHING not even the Log part.

What's happening? I'm at a complete loss.

Im on XCode 4.2 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

What's the return value from `printf`/`wprintf` in the case where you think it's not printing anything?  It *should* be returning either -1 in the case of a failure or 1 or more, since if successful, it should always print at least the newline character after the description string.

- If it's returning 1 or more, is the newline getting printed?  Have you tried piping the output of your program to a hex dumper such as [`hexdump -C`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump) or [`xxd(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xxd.1.html)?
- If it's returning -1, what is the value of `errno`?

If it turns out that `printf` is failing with the error `EILSEQ`, then what's quite likely happening is that your string contains some non-ASCII characters in it, since those cause [`wcstombs(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/mbstowcs.3.html) to fail in the default C locale.  In that case, the solution is to use [`setlocale(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/setlocale.3.html) to switch into a UTF-8 locale when your program starts up:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Run "locale -a" in the Terminal to get a list of all valid locales
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    ...
}
```

Comment: The printf´s are returning the expected lengths of the lines they are supposed to print, Yet nothing is printed in the console, not a new line, not single char, nothing, nada, nil. Ill try UTF8, and Ill get back to you.